# ufw says a port is open, everyone else disagrees

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, firewall, ufw

I am running apache2 on Ubuntu 9.10, and I want expose a particular site through port 10045.

My first instinct was to go to ufw and open that port. I've done that, and if I do a list of rules in ufw I get this:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
9418/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
10045/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
```

But if I run nmap I get this:

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-08-02 18:15 BST
Interesting ports on myserver (192.168.1.65):
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
9418/tcp open  unknown
```

And if I check specifically for 10045:

```
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
10045/tcp closed unknown
```

If I try and visit the web site, then I just get a timeout.

What do I have to do to get the port open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closed` means that no service is listening to that port.

Did you check that Apache is actually listening on it ? do `netstat -ltpn`, see if 10045 is listed as bound by Apache.

Did you add the proper Listen directive to apache configuration ? did you restart it afterwards ?

Comment: in my ports.conf I have `NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.65:10045`
and in 000-default in sites-enabled I have `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.65:10045>...`. Is that enough?

Comment: I see it now! I didn't have `Listen 10045`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Damn wasted 2 hours. 
Point is I did fire up vagrant machine with ubuntu 16. 
Then I did install couchdb 2.1 And try to access couch from outside. ( curl 192.168.33.10:5984 ) Curl said connection refused. But  nmap said

```
(env27) [codertarasvaskiv@lodestone trash]$ nmap -Pn 192.168.33.10 -p 5984
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-13 12:22 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.33.10
Host is up (0.00052s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5984/tcp closed couchdb
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.56 seconds
```

So I did try to open port with ufw help. On 192.168.33.10 ( sudo ufw allow 5984) And restarted ufw service.

```
ubuntu@client:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From 

--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
5984                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5984 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But this did not help. Nmap said the same "port is closed"

So my solution was: I edited /opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini  and changed  bind_addres = 0.0.0.0 under [chttp] part. That did work. Nmap now says port is open.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5984/tcp open  couchdb
```